# Variables set in previous chunks are inherited in case of R chunks only (R markdown)

Tags: python, r, knitr, r-markdown

According to: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/ numerous languages are handled by Rmarkdown.

However, I noticed that only R! chunks seems to inherits variables from previous chunks.

For example, following .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Variables inheritance in next chunk"
output: pdf_document
---

## Set variable

```{r defineVector}
w = as.vector(c(2,6,7,5,7,8,5,7,6))
```

## Print mean

```{r meanValue, echo=TRUE}
mean(w)
```
````

compiles well:

[image: variables inherited for R code]

but exact counterpart for Python (Python chunks instead of R chunks):

````
---
title: "Variables inheritance in next chunk"
output: pdf_document
---

## Set variable

```{python defineVector}
w=[2,6,7,5,7,8,5,7,6]
```

## Print mean

```{python meanValue, echo=TRUE}
# Following line results in: <module> NameError: name 'w' is not defined
print(sum(w) / float(len(w)))
# However if I repeat line: w=[2,6,7,5,7,8,5,7,6]
# before print, document works - compiles to PDF
```
````

gives an error ( NameError: name 'w' is not defined):

[image: error for Python chunk]

Is there any option to set all chunks to behave exactly the same way for all languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually in the link provided by the OP: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/ (my emphasis)

> Except engine='R' (default), **all chunks are executed in separate sessions**, so the variables cannot be directly shared. If we want to make use of objects created in previous chunks, we usually have to write them to files (as side effects). For the bash engine, we can use Sys.setenv() to export variables from R to bash (example). Another approach is to use the (experimental) runr package.

Here is a vignette for the [runr package](http://rpubs.com/badbye/python-knitr).

Comment: The poor python support is a long-standing problem that I plan to address  in the (near) future with the new [reticulate](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate) package.